# wrong figure numbering in the list of figures (strange behavious with tabular and figure combination)

Tags: tables, floats, numbering

- The figure with label "label2" is wrong numbered in "List of Figures"
- I need this tabular thing inside figure environment because I want to "break" figure into two section which one of them will be continued in the next page (as MWE shows)
- Figure with "label3" is only additional componen which shows that without tabular environment "List of Figures" works properly

I need solution where figure with "label2" will be show in "List of Figures" **as unique number** (not the same as figure with "label1").

Please, help me! I spent hours on it... and just can't figure it out.

**MWE (here I temporary uploaded generated pdf from this MWE -> [click](https://file.io/mr0J0Fff)):**

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newcommand{\mylipsum}{just dummy text}
\newcommand{\Mylipsum}{\mylipsum{} \\ \mylipsum \\ \mylipsum \\ \mylipsum}

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{a4paper,inner=3.5cm,outer=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.65\linewidth]{img/test.png}
    \caption{something}
    \label{subfig:1}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.65\linewidth]{img/test.png}
    \caption{something1}
    \label{subfig:2}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill \\
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.65\linewidth]{img/test.png}
    \caption{something2}
    \label{subfig:3}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill 
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
    \centering    
    \includegraphics[width=0.65\linewidth]{img/test.png}
    \caption{something3}
    \label{subfig:4}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill 
\caption[why the same number, it's figure \textbf{label1}]{\Mylipsum \\ \mylipsum}
\label{fig:label1}
\end{figure}

\noindent \Mylipsum
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
    \includegraphics[width=.33\textwidth]{img/test.png}&
    \includegraphics[width=.33\textwidth]{img/test.png}&
    \includegraphics[width=.33\textwidth]{img/test.png}\\
(a) & (b) & (c) \\[6pt]
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[H]\ContinuedFloat
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
    \includegraphics[width=.33\textwidth]{img/test.png}&
    \includegraphics[width=.33\textwidth]{img/test.png}\\
(d) & (e) \\[6pt]
\end{tabular}
\caption[why the same number, it's figure \textbf{label2}]{something1;
(b) something2;
(c) something3;
(d) something4;
(e) something5.
}
\label{fig:label2}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.33\textwidth]{img/test.png}
\caption[correct numbering]{correct numbering}
\label{fig:label3}
\end{figure}

\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Spis rysunków}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have a `\ContinuedFloat` in your second figure and so it shares its number with the previous figure.

Comment: Dear @UlrikeFischer that was soooo helpful! I wrote a hundreds pages with latex and just can't see this mistake. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `\ContinuedFloat` in your second figure and so it shares its number with the previous figure.